# compare tchar[] and char[]

Tags: visual-c++

How do you compare two values like:

```
TCHAR s[100];
CHAR d[100];
```

Both variables have a value, so how do you compare the values?

Answer (score 1):

I would convert both values to the same type before attempting a compare.

```
BOOL UnicodeToAnsi(LPWSTR pszwUniString, LPSTR  pszAnsiBuff, DWORD  dwAnsiBuffSize){
int iRet = 0;
    iRet = WideCharToMultiByte(
    CP_ACP,
    0,
    pszwUniString,
    -1,
    pszAnsiBuff,
    dwAnsiBuffSize,
    NULL,
    NULL
    );
return ( 0 != iRet );
```

}

```
BOOL AnsiToUnicode(LPSTR  pszAnsiString, LPWSTR pszwUniBuff, DWORD dwUniBuffSize){

int iRet = 0;
    iRet = MultiByteToWideChar(
    CP_ACP,
    0,
    pszAnsiString,
    -1,
    pszwUniBuff,
    dwUniBuffSize
    );

return ( 0 != iRet );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about using [lexicographical_compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/) and a function like

```
bool mycomp (TCHAR c1, char c2)
{ return tolower(c1)<tolower(c2); }
bool mycomp (char c1, TCHAR c2)
{ return tolower(c1)<tolower(c2); }
```